# SpringMVC RequestMapping params with combined style expressions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC project where I am trying to parse URLs such as:

`http://localhost:8080/app/my-controller?param1=a&param2=256`
`http://localhost:8080/app/my-controller?param1=b&param2=256`
`http://localhost:8080/app/my-controller?param1=c&param2=256`

I would like the controller to accept requests having both param1 and  param2 but also limit the values of param1.

I tried the following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my-controller")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(params = { "param1=a", "param1=b", "param1=c", "param2" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity action(@RequestParam(name = "param1", required = true) String param1, @RequestParam(name = "param2", required = true) Integer param2) {
        ...
    }

}
```

But the URLs shown above don't match.

How to specify RequestMapping parameter values using a sequence of "myParam=myValue" and "myParam" style expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you specified `param2` in params list as well, what is not needed. Try simply remove it from params list, leaving rest code as it is:

```
params = { "param1=a", "param1=b", "param1=c"}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem. I thought I should add all possible parameters to the params attribute but it serves only to narrow down the primary mapping, specifying param2 as required does the rest.